# flutter_blue_plus is not showing devices after scanning

Tags: android, flutter

I have a simple flutter application , i want to scan ble devices and connect to them , the problem is that the scanResults always empty , below is my code for the controller and the view

Controller

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class BleConnexionController extends GetxController {
  //TODO: Implement BleConnexionController

  late BluetoothDevice connectedDevice;
  Stream<List<ScanResult>> get scanResults => FlutterBluePlus.scanResults;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    initializeBluetooth();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
  }

  Future<void> initializeBluetooth() async {
    // Request Bluetooth permissions
    final status = await Permission.bluetooth.status;
    print('the status $status');
    if (status.isGranted) {
      // Bluetooth permission is granted, now turn on Bluetooth
      // Check if Bluetooth is available on the device
      if (await FlutterBluePlus.isAvailable) {
        // Check if Bluetooth is already on
        final state = await FlutterBluePlus.adapterState.first;
        if (state == BluetoothAdapterState.off) {
          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            try{
              await FlutterBluePlus.turnOn();
            }catch(e){
              print(e);
            }
          }
        }
        // You can now use FlutterBlue to work with Bluetooth devices
        // Example: List<BluetoothDevice> devices = await flutterBlue.connectedDevices;
      } else {
        // Bluetooth is not available on this device
        print('Bluetooth is not available on this device.');
      }
    } else {
      // Permission not granted
      print('Bluetooth permission not granted.');
    }
  }
  var subscription = FlutterBluePlus.scanResults.listen(
          (results) {
        for (ScanResult r in results) {
            print('${r.device.remoteId}: "${r.device.localName}" found! rssi: ${r.rssi}');
        }
      },
      onError: (e) => print(e)
  );

  Future scan() async {
    List<BluetoothDevice> devices = await FlutterBluePlus.connectedSystemDevices;
    // Start scanning
    await FlutterBluePlus.startScan(timeout: const Duration(milliseconds: 100), androidUsesFineLocation: false); // Stop scanning
    await FlutterBluePlus.stopScan();
  }
}
```

the scan function is called in the view when pressing scan button

the view

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../controllers/ble_connexion_controller.dart';

class BleConnexionView extends GetView<BleConnexionController> {
  const BleConnexionView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BleConnexionView'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: GetBuilder<BleConnexionController>(
        init: BleConnexionController(),
        builder: (controller)  {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => controller.scan(),
                child: Text("Scan"),),
              ),
              StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: controller.scanResults,
                builder: (context,snapshot){
                  if (snapshot.data != null && snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty){
                    return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    final data = snapshot.data![index];
                      return Card(
                        elevation: 2,
                        child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(data.device.localName),
                        subtitle: Text(data.device.id.id),
                        trailing: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                        controller.connectedDevice=data.device;
                        //controller.connectDevice().then((value) => Get.off(const HomePage()));
                      },
                      child: Text("Connect"),
                      ),
                        ),
                    );
                  },
                 );
              }else{
                  return const Center(child: Text("No devices found"),);
                 }
               })
              ]),
           );
        },),
    );}
}
```

i tried many flutter versions (3.13.3
3.13.2
3.10.6 (active)
3.10.0
)
the scanResults builder is always empty , and no device is detected , can someone help  ?